# Upgrading SOLR from 3.5 to 5.2

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a running SOLR 3.5 instance with 30 GB of data indexes, i want to upgrade solr to the latest version (5.2),i want to know how to upgrade the instance without corrupting the indexes ?